# How come Angular http.post invoked without `.subscribe`?

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular-routing, canactivate

Looking at this `authguard` which is called from `canactivate` :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private loginServicePOST:LoginService, private router:Router) { }

    canActivate(next:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return this.loginServicePOST({...}).map(e => {
            if (e) {
                return true;
            }
        }).catch(() => {

            return Observable.of(false);
        });
    }   
}
```

This code is working and an http request is invoked to server.

**Question :**

This is a *cold* observable and no one `.subscribe`s to it - so I don't understand how this `post` request is invoked and why.
`subscribe` must be written IMHO.

NB
 I already know that `canactivate` can return `bool`/`Promise<bool>`/`Observable<bool>`

Comment: I can't see a post request in your question

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the `loginService` is making a post request. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router is subscribing to the observable returned by `canActivate` which invokes the observable returned by `loginService(...).map(...)`

Comment: Yes, it's done behind the scene by the router if it recognizes the return value as `Observable`.